# First 16 bytes of AES-128 CFB-8 decryption are damaged

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, protocols, crypto++

I've been working on a project recently that should connect to a server with the help of a protocol. So far so good, but when I combed to decrypt the packages, I quickly noticed that something is not working properly.

The first 16 bytes of all packets are decrypted incorrectly. I have tried it with different libraries but that does not work either. I work in the C++ language and have so far used Crypto++ and OpenSSL for decryption, without success.

Under this [Link](https://wiki.vg/index.php?title=Protocol&oldid=7368) you can find the protocol, here the decryption protocol [Link](https://wiki.vg/Protocol_Encryption) and here is my corresponding code:

OpenSSL:

```c
void init() {

    unsigned char* sharedSecret = new unsigned char[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];

    std::generate(sharedSecret,
        sharedSecret + AES_BLOCK_SIZE,
        std::bind(&RandomGenerator::GetInt, &m_RNG, 0, 255));

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        sharedSecretKey += sharedSecret[i];
    }

    // Initialize AES encryption and decryption
    if (!(m_EncryptCTX = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()))
        std::cout << "123" << std::endl;

    if (!(EVP_EncryptInit_ex(m_EncryptCTX, EVP_aes_128_cfb8(), nullptr, (unsigned char*)sharedSecretKey.c_str(), (unsigned char*)sharedSecretKey.c_str())))
        std::cout << "123" << std::endl;

    if (!(m_DecryptCTX = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()))
        std::cout << "123" << std::endl;

    if (!(EVP_DecryptInit_ex(m_DecryptCTX, EVP_aes_128_cfb8(), nullptr, (unsigned char*)sharedSecretKey.c_str(), (unsigned char*)sharedSecretKey.c_str())))
        std::cout << "123" << std::endl;

    m_BlockSize = EVP_CIPHER_block_size(EVP_aes_128_cfb8());
}

std::string result;
int size = 0;
result.resize(1000);
EVP_DecryptUpdate(m_DecryptCTX, &((unsigned char*)result.c_str())[0], &size, &sendString[0], data.size());
```

Crypto++:

```cpp
CryptoPP::CFB_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Decryption AESDecryptor((byte*)sharedSecret.c_str(), (unsigned int)16, sharedSecret.c_str(), 1);

std::string sTarget("");
CryptoPP::StringSource ss(data, true, new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter(AESDecryptor, new CryptoPP::StringSink(sTarget)));
```

I think important to mention is that I use one and the same shared secret for the key and the iv (initialization vector). In other posts, this was often labeled as a problem. I do not know how to fix it in this case because the protocol want it.

I would be looking forward to a constructive feedback.

Comment: Please supply a test vector for your protocol.

Comment: I have supply a test binary array down. Or do you mean sth. else?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> EVP_EncryptInit_ex(m_EncryptCTX, EVP_aes_128_cfb8(), nullptr,
>     (unsigned char*)sharedSecretKey.c_str(), (unsigned char*)sharedSecretKey.c_str()))
> ```
>
> And:
>
> ```
> CFB_Mode<AES>::Decryption AESDecryptor((byte*)sharedSecret.c_str(),
>     (unsigned int)16, sharedSecret.c_str(), 1);
>
> std::string sTarget("");
> StringSource ss(data, true, new StreamTransformationFilter(AESDecryptor, new StringSink(sTarget)));
> ```

It is not readily apparent, but you need to set feedback size for the mode of operation of the block cipher in Crypto++. The Crypto++ feedback size is 128 by default.

The code to set the feedback size of CFB mode can be found at [CFB Mode](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/CFB_Mode) on the Crypto++ wiki. You want the 3rd or 4th example down the page.

```cpp
AlgorithmParameters params =
        MakeParameters(Name::FeedbackSize(), 1 /*8-bits*/)
        (Name::IV(), ConstByteArrayParameter(iv));
```

That is kind of an awkward way to pass parameters. It is documented in the sources files and on the wiki at [NameValuePairs](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/NameValuePairs). It allows you to pass arbitrary parameters through consistent interfaces. It is powerful once you acquire a taste for it.

And then use `params` to key the encryptor and decryptor:

```cpp
CFB_Mode< AES >::Encryption enc;
enc.SetKey( key, key.size(), params );

// CFB mode must not use padding. Specifying
//  a scheme will result in an exception
StringSource ss1( plain, true, 
   new StreamTransformationFilter( enc,
      new StringSink( cipher )
   ) // StreamTransformationFilter      
); // StringSource
```

I believe your calls would look something like this (if I am parsing the OpenSSL correctly):

```cpp
const byte* ptr = reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(sharedSecret.c_str());

AlgorithmParameters params =
        MakeParameters(Name::FeedbackSize(), 1 /*8-bits*/)
        (Name::IV(), ConstByteArrayParameter(ptr, 16));

CFB_Mode< AES >::Encryption enc;
enc.SetKey( ptr, 16, params );
```

---

In your production code you should use unique key and iv. So do something like this using [HKDF](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Hkdf):

```cpp
std::string seed(AES_BLOCK_SIZE, '0');
std::generate(seed, seed + AES_BLOCK_SIZE,
    std::bind(&RandomGenerator::GetInt, &m_RNG, 0, 255));

SecByteBlock sharedSecret(32);
const byte usage[] = "Key and IV v1";

HKDF<SHA256> hkdf;
hkdf.DeriveKey(sharedSecret, 32, &seed[0], 16, usage, COUNTOF(usage), nullptr, 0);

AlgorithmParameters params =
        MakeParameters(Name::FeedbackSize(), 1 /*8-bits*/)
        (Name::IV(), ConstByteArrayParameter(sharedSecret+16, 16));

CFB_Mode< AES >::Encryption enc;
enc.SetKey(sharedSecret+0, 0, params);
```

In the code above, `sharedSecret` is twice as large as it needs to be. You derive the key and iv from the seed using `HDKF`. `sharedSecret+0` is the 16-byte key, and `sharedSecret+16` is the 16-byte iv.

Comment: @DerCoder - No, sorry. You need to post a test vector to investigate it further.

Comment: How should I publish it? As a byte / char array just post as a comment or how do you imagine that?

Comment: jww you have now a test vector in base64 format. You will find that above